# Excel Validation List Formula Generates Error When Formula Evaluation Finds None

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, validation

So I've been trying to work with dynamic drop-down lists in data validation, and I've had a lot of success, but for some reason this particular formula is kicking my butt:

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(A2&"SL1"),1,1)),A1,INDIRECT(A2&"SL"&INDEX(LevelO, V2, MATCH(A2, LevelO[#Headers]))))`

I've used all components of that before with no issues.  However, the last INDEX is causing issues.  If I remove that and hardcode the column number instead so it looks like this:

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(A2&"SL1"),1,1)),A1,INDIRECT(A2&"SL"&9))`

Then it works fine.  Why can't I use an INDEX function inside an INDIRECT function when it's fine the other way around?  By the way, all of the applicable tables and ranges exist, that's not an issue.  When I put the first formula into a cell it evaluates all of the named ranges just fine (using formula evaluation).  This is with Excel 2007.

Comment: So you are saying if you just put `=INDEX(LevelO, V2, MATCH(P2, LevelO[#Headers]))` into a cell you do get 9?

Comment: Depending on the value of V2, it can return anything from 0 to 9.  LevelO[#Headers] has A2 (which is what P2 should have been, but changing that changes nothing, I'll make sure that's updated in the question), and that column has the numbers from 0-9.  It returns every time.

Comment: But like I said, I run it through an evaluation and that value never returns errored.

Comment: `INDIRECT` has volatile behavior. This causes problems in multiple cases. In this case (Data Validation) it causes problems with the Table references `LevelO` and `LevelO[#Headers]`. Replace those with cell references and it will work in Data validation also. Try avoid `INDIRECT` or work around avoiding Table references.

Comment: *lol* sh*** volatile functions. Please try `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(A2&"SL1"),1,1)),A1,INDIRECT(A2&"SL"&INDEX(INDIRECT("LevelO"), V2, MATCH(A2, INDIRECT("LevelO[#Headers]")))))`. So getting the Table references also by `INDIRECT`. This works in my test case.

Comment: +1 for an almost working solution, however AHC's answer is more what I needed because of the character length limit within validation formula entry boxes.  Changing it to do what this comment suggests brings it perilously close to the limit, and doesn't leave me any leeway for making the formula bigger if I needed.  Still, a good workaround for more small-scale applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can create a **name** in the **name manager** in the ***Formula Tab**, and then give a name to your new *name* and put your formula in the **refers to**. Once done, you can use the same name in the data validation, instead of putting down your formula in the refers to box, insert the name you created.
It should work.

Comment: I'd give another +1 if I could for such a creative answer.  It never occurred to me that you could put formulas like that in there with the name manager.  I had already converted that table to named ranges for other reference, but that's so simplistic that I'm tempted to change it all back!